# What is the voltage at highlighted point? How can I derive it?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

Assume this op amp symbol as graphic representation.

Comment: Is this a theoretical *Ideal Opamp*? What do we know about the properties of Ideal Opamps?

Comment: @brhans Yes. I need to how to derive it mathematically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That node should be 1 Volt. (assuming ideal op-amp)

You can run this schematic to see the output at node Vp:
(Simulate -> DC -> Run DC Solver)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFy3D2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To understand why this is so, first you must understand how an (ideal) op-amp works:

1. The input nodes of an op-amp do not pass any current (\$I_p = I_n = 0 A\$)
2. If there is a feedback between the output of an op-amp and its negative input node (Vn), the voltage between Vp and Vn should be equal (Vp = Vn).

Now to derive the Vp voltage, the 1st rule dictates that no current should pass into the positive node of the op-amp (Ip = 0) and so the current of R1 should also be 0. Since there's no current, you can derive the voltage at Vp using the basic Ohm's law formula:
$$\frac{(V1 - Vp)}{R1} = 0 A$$
$$\therefore Vp = 1 V$$